# How do I bold specific formula in a concatenate formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
CONCATENATE("A/C  ",(+VLOOKUP(A5,'02'!$B$6:$G$65536,3,FALSE)),"/ AT  ",(+VLOOKUP(A5,'02'!$B$6:$G$65536,4,FALSE))," /  ON ",(+VLOOKUP(A5,'02'!$B$6:$G$65536,5,FALSE)),"/ Bill No",(+VLOOKUP(A5,'02'!$B$6:$G$65536,6,FALSE
```

I need to bold all the `VLOOKUP` formula through an Excel formula or VBA.

Comment: Bold? What do you mean? Do you need to place in bold font?

Comment: i need the vlookup formula answer to be in bold font

Comment: entire cell value can be bold not only vlookup value:)

Comment: You will need to write the results to the cell as a text string, and use VBA to bold the particular characters.

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA it is not possible.
There is a "tricky" way, if you have just a few.

1) Place your formula

2) Insert a textbox

3) Insert 1 rectangle shape

4) Click on the shape, then click in the formula bar, then enter the “=Cell Address” (eg =A1)

5) Set the fill and outline of the shapes to blank

6) Enter the static text in the textbox

7) Group the shape and textbox to give this some stability

Hope it helps